# DIV content inside Repeater not controllable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, repeater

Inside a repeater's ItemTemplate, I have..

```
retstr.AppendLine("<div id='contentDivImg' style='display: block;'><img src = '" & img_src & "' /></div>")
```

Every image needs to hide and show when the toggle button/link is pressed. Although, **only the first IMAGE/DIV toggles visibility**, none of the following images whose paths are also gotten from the database by the line of code above. Why? I've tried using class instead of id parameter.

Here is the javascript only if interested..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle(showHideDiv, switchImgTag) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(showHideDiv);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        if (ele.style.display == "block") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="/images/Show.png">';
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="/images/Hide.png">';
        }
    }
</script>
```

And, here is the simple toggle link to show and hide the conntentDivImage when clicked..

```
<a id="imageDivLink" href="javascript:toggle('contentDivImg', 'imageDivLink');"><img src="/images/Hide.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

getElementById only returns the first element by that ID, and so therefore the 1st one is the only one that is going to work according to your code. I would add a counter for use in your ItemTemplates to give each div a unique ID, like contentDivImg1 and contentDivImg2, and then when you have the ItemTemplate for the anchor tag, make sure to reference the right one when calling your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in HTML, IDs are meant to be unique. `document.getElementById()` stops after finding the first element with a matching ID. In this case, it finds the first `<div>` and ignores the rest of the page.

However, you can change the way that you use your repeater to better suit your needs:

If you restructure your repeater to look more like this:

```
<!-- the repeater now has an OnItemDataBound event -->
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptDivs" OnItemDataBound="rptDivs_OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <!-- The <div>, <img>, and <a> tags have runat="server". This is important. -->
    <div runat="server" ID="div"><img runat="server" ID="img" />
         <a id="a" runat="server"><img src="/Images/Hide.png" id="img2" runat="server" /></a>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

...then each `<div>` and `<img />` within the repeater will have a unique id. The ID will look something like this: ``.

You will need to add an event to your page's code behind to set the properties (such as `src`) for your HTML. Since you've added the `OnItemDataBound` event to the repeater, you can access the objects in your code behind (this is in C#, but the idea will still work in VB).

```
protected void rptDivs_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    // first, let's get the item that you have bound to your repeater
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject)e.Item.DataItem;

    //  You can access the image and div objects here because they are set to runat="server"
    HtmlImage img = (HtmlImage)e.Item.FindControl("img");
    HtmlImage buttonImg = (HtmlImage)e.Item.FindControl("img2");
    HtmlAnchor a = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("a");
    HtmlGenericControl div = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("div");

    //  you can now set the properties of the HTML in your code-behind
    img.Src = myObject.imgSrc;
    a.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:toggle('" + div.ID + "', '" + buttonImg.ID + "');";

}
```

The HTML output of each repeated element might now look something like this:

```
    <div ID="body_body_div_1"><img ID="body_body_img_1" />
         <a id="body_body_a_1" onclick="javascript:toggle('body_body_div_1', 'body_body_img_1');"><img src="/Images/Hide.png" id="body_body_img2_1" runat="server" /></a>
    </div>
```

...with the ID's changing between each repeated element.